# What does the "Cherry-Pick" menu item in the Git Extension for Visual Studio 2018 do?

Tags: git

I need to:

- Keep the last commit made to a Pull-Request.
- Remove the two commits prior to a Pull-Request.

In Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2019:

- I go to Team Explorer.
- I go to Branches.
- I right-click my local branch to bring up the local history.
- I right-click a commit that I would like to remove.

There is an item in the context menu: "Cherry-Pick".  Does "Cherry-Pick" select a commit that I want to keep or select a commit for removal?

Would the "Reset | Delete Changes (--hard)" be a way to remove a specific Commit?

The Git terminology is somewhat vague and opaque.

Comment: (Simple note : git terminology is quite clear. Blame VS Studio if something is unclear in their UI.)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=git+cherry-pick

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: Thanks all - the  "What does cherry-picking a commit with Git mean?" is useful.  I think I need a good Git guide that explains the direction (where changes are coming from and going to).  The problem I run into is that the documentation for one ambiguous Git command is explained in terms of other vague Git commands.  Git issues like the one that I am working through take far longer to resolve than the time required to make my code changes.